# Why are my code blocks not rendering in the Sandcastle Help File?

Tags: c#, sandcastle

I'm using the current version of Sandcastle from Codeplex that is integrated with VS.NET 2012 to build a `.cmh` help file. The help file is being created, but I can't seem to ever get any of my `<code>` blocks to emit in the help file. I have the following easy example I keep working with:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the summary 
/// </summary>
/// <code>var s;</code>
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

When I look at the output .chm file, the `var s;` code is not present *anywhere*. I have done the following:

- Added reference to `Code Block Component` in the Sandcastle project properties.
- Tried making tag `<code lang="C#">var s;</code>` and `<code language="C#">var s;</code>` but neither made a difference.
- Read documentation on the following sites detailing this process but to no avail:

  https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/.net-tools/taming-sandcastle-a-.net-programmers-guide-to-documenting-your-code/
  http://www.ewoodruff.us/shfbdocs/

The example is obviously a simplified version, but I'm just trying to get the basics work here. What am I doing incorrectly or missing?

Comment: I don't think the `code` tag is allowed to be by itself, try putting it inside an `<example>` tag, like `<example><code>var s;</code></example>`.

Comment: @vcsjones - Nice call, I swore I tried that before but I must of had something construed. I recommend providing your suggestion as the answer with a full example so I can mark it. Funny the 'Taming Sandcastle' article does not show it like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think the code tag is allowed to be by itself, try putting it inside an `<example>` tag, like `<example><code>var s;</code></example>`. So this should work:

```
/// <summary>
/// This is the summary 
/// </summary>
/// <example>
/// <code>var s;</code>
/// </example>
public string SomeValue { get; set; }
```

Comment: This solved the problem I had and now emits the code in an `Examples` section under the `Syntax` section that already existed. Thank you very much.